# Sole Tiller to deploy multiple namespace on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Couldn't be found at https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/rbac.md , Is Tiller able to install chart on the other multiple namespaces?

I hope there is one Tiller on kube-system namespace and there are also multiple namespaces: namespaceA, namespaceB, namespaceC, ... .

Finally I hope I can deploy nginx to multiple namespaces like:

```
helm init --service-account tiller --tiller-namespace kube-system
helm install nginx --tiller-namespace kube-system --namespace namespaceA
helm install nginx --tiller-namespace kube-system --namespace namespaceB
```

I'd like to know if it is possible and how can Service Accounts, Roles and Role Bindings be set.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with clustetRoles instead of Roles, this way you can grant permissions in all namespaces. The clusterrole, clusterrolebinding and serviceaccount code would be:

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: tiller-manager
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "batch", "extensions", "apps"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: tiller-binding
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: tiller
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: tiller-manager
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: tiller
  namespace: kube-system
```

If you only want to grant permissions to few namespaces, you should create a rolebinding in each namespace like this:

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: tiller-binding
  namespace: namespaceA
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: tiller
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: tiller-manager
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind directions. Yes, the simple answer is to use ClusterRole. 
I prefer using Role instead because Tiller ServiceAccount should not operate resources on kube-system namespace. 
Does that make sense?

    kind: Role
    metadata:
      name: namespaceA-tiller-manager
      namespace: namespaceA
    (snip)
    ---
    kind: RoleBinding
    metadata:
      name: namespaceA-tiller-binding
      namespace: namespaceA
    subjects:
    - kind: ServiceAccount
      name: tiller
      namespace: namespaceA
    (snip)

Comment: Yes, you can define a role + roleBinding per namespace or just define the clusterRole and grant it to specific namespace with rolebindings (see my last piece of code). The result will be the same, the clusterrole will only work in the namespaces with rolebindings.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding